# Show and hide element through Javascript

Tags: javascript

In given below code I want to include **show and hidden** feature.
There are three header tags with the unordered list in my code. 
By default all unordered list are hidden.
When I click on first header then it displays its corresponding unordered list.
After it if I click on second/third header then it is not hiding previously opened unordered list.

**What i want** : when clicking on a header, previously opened `unordered list` must not display.

> Try to understand my question by running below code.

```js
//JAVASCRIPT
let selectAllHeader = document.querySelectorAll('header');

function show_article(e) {
  let parent = e.target.parentNode.children[1]; // selects ul
  parent.className = "show";
}

for (let i = 0; i < selectAllHeader.length; i++) {
  addEventListener('click', show_article);
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

article {
  float: left;
}

article:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

article:nth-child(2n) header {
  background-color: #7b9dc9;
}

article:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

article:nth-child(odd) header {
  background-color: #e595a1;
}

header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: circle
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<main>
  <!--article 1 -->
  <article id="a1">
    <div>
      <header>
        NANO AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </article>

  <!--article 2 -->
  <article id="a2">
    <div>
      <header>
        GEDIT AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </article>

  <!--article 3 -->
  <article id="a3">
    <div>
      <header>
        TEXTMATE AREA
      </header>


      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>

</main>
```

Help me...

Comment: so when all the `header` will be hidden then how you want them to display again?

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. What problem are you running into exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to select all the already `.show` and change them to `.hidden` and then atlast changed the clicked header children to `.show`. In this way only 1 `<ul>` will have class `show`

```js
//JAVASCRIPT
let selectAllHeader = document.querySelectorAll('header');

function show_article(e) {
  document.querySelectorAll('ul.show').forEach(ul=>{
    ul.className="hidden"
  })
  let parent = e.target.parentNode.children[1]; // selects ul
  parent.className = "show";
  
}

for (let i = 0; i < selectAllHeader.length; i++) {
  addEventListener('click', show_article);
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

article {
  float: left;
}

article:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

article:nth-child(2n) header {
  background-color: #7b9dc9;
}

article:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

article:nth-child(odd) header {
  background-color: #e595a1;
}

header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: circle
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul.show < div < article < main > ul{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<main>
  <!--article 1 -->
  <article id="a1">
    <div>
      <header>
        NANO AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </article>

  <!--article 2 -->
  <article id="a2">
    <div>
      <header>
        GEDIT AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </article>

  <!--article 3 -->
  <article id="a3">
    <div>
      <header>
        TEXTMATE AREA
      </header>


      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>

</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you only add the click eventlistener to the headers, not all elements! Also before you add the `show` class to the ul belonging to the header, first remove all other show classes from the ul's of the other headers. I have also changed the adding of the show class to toggling of the show class so on a second click on the same header the menu closes again:

```js
//JAVASCRIPT
var selectAllHeader = document.querySelectorAll('header');

function show_article(e) {
    for (let i = 0; i < selectAllHeader.length; i++) {
        selectAllHeader[i].parentNode.children[1].classList.remove("show");
    }
    let parent = e.target.parentNode.children[1]; // selects ul
    parent.classList.toggle("show");
}

for (let i = 0; i < selectAllHeader.length; i++) {
   selectAllHeader[i].addEventListener('click', show_article);
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

article {
  float: left;
}

article:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

article:nth-child(2n) header {
  background-color: #7b9dc9;
}

article:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

article:nth-child(odd) header {
  background-color: #e595a1;
}

header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: circle
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<main>
  <!--article 1 -->
  <article id="a1">
    <div>
      <header>
        NANO AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </article>

  <!--article 2 -->
  <article id="a2">
    <div>
      <header>
        GEDIT AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </article>

  <!--article 3 -->
  <article id="a3">
    <div>
      <header>
        TEXTMATE AREA
      </header>


      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//JAVASCRIPT
let selectAllHeader = document.querySelectorAll('header');
let selectAllUL = Array.from(selectAllHeader).map(header =>  header.parentNode.querySelector('ul'));

function show_article(e) {
  
  let parent = e.target.parentNode.querySelector('ul') // selects ul
  
  selectAllUL.forEach(function(node) {
    node.classList.remove('show');
     node.classList.add('hidden');
     });
  parent.classList.add('show');
  parent.classList.remove('hidden');
}

for (let i = 0; i < selectAllHeader.length; i++) {
  addEventListener('click', show_article);
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

article {
  float: left;
}

article:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

article:nth-child(2n) header {
  background-color: #7b9dc9;
}

article:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

article:nth-child(odd) header {
  background-color: #e595a1;
}

header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: circle
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<main>
  <!--article 1 -->
  <article id="a1">
    <div>
      <header>
        NANO AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </article>

  <!--article 2 -->
  <article id="a2">
    <div>
      <header>
        GEDIT AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </article>

  <!--article 3 -->
  <article id="a3">
    <div>
      <header>
        TEXTMATE AREA
      </header>


      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>

</main>
```

Not the most elegant solution. But should solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `.show` class from all your elements and replace it with `hidden`, and only once you have done that add the `.show` class to the click element.

See working example below:

```js
//JAVASCRIPT
let selectAllHeader = document.querySelectorAll('header');

function show_article(e) {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.show')].forEach(elem => {
    elem.classList.remove('show');
    elem.classList.add("hidden");
  });
  let parent = e.target.parentNode.children[1]; // selects ul
  parent.className = "show";
}

for (let i = 0; i < selectAllHeader.length; i++) {
  addEventListener('click', show_article);
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

article {
  float: left;
}

article:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

article:nth-child(2n) header {
  background-color: #7b9dc9;
}

article:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

article:nth-child(odd) header {
  background-color: #e595a1;
}

header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: circle
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<main>
  <!--article 1 -->
  <article id="a1">
    <div>
      <header>
        NANO AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </article>

  <!--article 2 -->
  <article id="a2">
    <div>
      <header>
        GEDIT AREA
      </header>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </article>

  <!--article 3 -->
  <article id="a3">
    <div>
      <header>
        TEXTMATE AREA
      </header>


      <ul class="hidden">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>

</main>
```